# How to properly open files/applications as root?

Tags: sudo, d-bus

When I try to open a file manager as root calling, for instance, `sudo thunar` the units at left appear with no labels (also some that shouldn't appear, like dev, pts, proc, sys):

[image]

If I call `sudo dbus-launch thunar` it loads just fine (just like as normal user), however after closing the application a `dbus-daemon` instance keeps running forever.

If I call `sudo dbus-run-session -- thunar` it loads just fine, so it looks the right way of doing it. However if I want to open a file instead of an application I need to call either `xdg-open` or `gio open` (e.g `sudo dbus-run-session -- xdg-open /home/test.txt` or `sudo dbus-run-session -- gio open /home/test.txt`), but in both cases when browsing a file from inside the application, the units appear in the wrong way and the terminal output is massively filled with the following:

```
(mousepad:7837): dconf-WARNING **: 19:33:35.947: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Is there a good solution for this mess?

Tested on Slackware Live Xfce from December 2021. But it doesn't really matter which distro -- the same thing happens in Ubuntu too.

**Note**: I would really appreciate if people skip the 'why you want to do that/you should not do that'. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean open a file instead of an application? How can you open a file without and app?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using. And can you also explain why you want to open graphical tools as root? That is not generally recommended. Finally, does using `pkexec` help?

Comment: Done. Thanks. Using `pkexec` doesn't change anything. You can test yourself since this issue is not distro related.

Comment: Well, it is likely distro and OS related (this site is not dedicated to Linux) but will certainly be desktop-manager related, and I can't test since I don't have thunar installed nor do I use it. I read your note and realize you don't want to hear this, but you are doing something that isn't supposed to be done, so it is normal that you have issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to run apps as root.

To edit a file as root, use `sudoedit`:

```
sudoedit file
```

To use a different editor do:

```
EDITOR=by_favourite_editor sudoedit file
```

Comment: While true, this isn't answering the question.

Comment: @Terdon. It is answering a possible need. The OP or future readers may be trying to run an editor as root, when they should be using `sudoedit`. I agree that it does not solve the problem for other apps.

Comment: Maybe so, but this isn't the question. The main question here is about opening a GUI app, specifically a file manager. The OP also asks how to use sudo to open a file but note that they mention xdg-open which means that it might not be a file that is opened for editing, it could well be a PDF or an image, so `sudoedit` won't help. Finally, I think you meant `EDITOR` (although `SUDO_EDITOR` would be more appropriate) and not `editor`.

Comment: Yes if it is to view a pdf, the another technique would be needed. Such as appropriate permissions. Any answer that targets the question directly will probably result in a bad outcome.